# How to send a text to multiple recipients with personalised details filled in from their contact information?

Tags: sms

Is they a way to send a text message to multiple recipients but include details taken from their contact card and have them automatically inserted into the text when it's sent? Something like the following:

> Merry Xmas `[contact name]`!

Where the name of the contact is filled in automatically. I'm aware that there are apps that allow mail merging of e-mails but I couldn't find any similar functionality for texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any stock messaging apps amongst any of the ROMs that will do that, but it looks like there are a bunch of apps in the market that will (Like [SMeSsaggia bulk customized SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gr.learn2develop.smessaggia&hl=en) or [Group SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobappli.groupsms&hl=en), or [Group SMS and Scheduler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.baole.app.groupsmsad2&hl=en).)

Answer (score -2):

To send a test to multiple recipients, just press the comma `,` button after each phone number. Once done, just send. All recipient numbers will line up on top of the phone number window after each comma.

Comment: And how does that answer the question?